# Expression to replace a section of test

Tags: notepad++

I have a large xml file that I'm trying to replace text in and would like to replace sections of the test with other text.  Below are example tags that I would like to modify.  The section of each tag _ACK I wouuld like to replace with _HSK.  The quantity of characters between the ] (right bracket) and the _ (underscrore) is different from each tag.  I'm having trouble writing an expression in Notepad++ to perform this.  Any help would be appreciated.  I have over 2000 lines that need to be changed.

ack-tag="{[Hialeah_RO_Main]AI_VT_1202B.H_ACK}"
ack-tag="{[Hialeah_RO_Main]AI_VT_1202B.HH_ACK}"
ack-tag="{[Hialeah_RO_Main]AI_AIT_2021_FAIL_AL_ACK}"

Thanks,
Shane

Comment: Can’t you just do a simple find-and-replace of `_ACK`→`_HSK`? If that’s not what you want, then edit the question to include the desired target strings in addition to the sample source strings.

Comment: no because I have several other locations where _ACK is being used throughtout the file that I do on want to replace.

Comment: What’s the difference? How can you determine which ones should be replaced and which ones should not? Is it only ones starting with `AI_…`? Only ones with a closing-brace immediately after `_ACK`? Some other criteria?

Comment: By your example, I would use find and replace `_ACK}"` → `_HSK}"`. Is this what you want? This will only match the `_ACK` preceded with `}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Within notepad++ replace dialog.

Use Regular Expresssion

if there is additional correction required after the ] before the _ACK then switch (.*) $2 with another replacement requirement.

Search and replace

```
(\])(.*)_ACK(\}")
```

replace

```
$1$2_HSK$3
```